# Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS not Starts GUI

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, ati

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on my HP Pavilion G4 1115br and when I start it does not load the GUI: [Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS problem in not Loads GUI - Part 1/2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjYsNPcS2OU). After I shut it down manually and start appears Grub and only then the GUI is loaded: [Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS problem in not Loads GUI - Part 2/2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcsi3djz37A).

Comments:

1. The system is installed from a Live USB.
2. What is more funny is that in the previous version, the 14.04 without
   update for 14.04.3, Ubuntu ran quiet. I had put Fedora 22 with the 64-bit architecture and also ran quiet.
3. System is light, it is only with this problem even at the time of boot, the rest runs beautifully.

The Graphics settings from my notebook are:

- Processor: VISION A4 Technology from AMD with AMD accelerated two A4-3300M cores (2.5 GHz / 1.9 GHz, 2 MB L2 cache)
- Processor Architecture: 64-bit
- Memory RAM: 3 GB DDR3 System Memory (2 DIMM)
- HD: 500GB (5400 RPM)
- Video Card: Radeon HD 6470G2 Dual AMD with 512MB of DDR3
- Screen: HP BrightView LED Display 14.0 "HD (1366 x 768)

Comment: Shit!!!!! Always have someone to edit my question! Is there anyone to answer it?